# Censored conditional expectation of a product of normals

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals

I am looking for the solution to:

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=?? 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
P \\
V^{*}
\end{pmatrix}\sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{p} \\
\mu_{v^{*}}
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{p} & \sigma_{v^{*},p} \\
\sigma_{v^{*},p}  & \sigma_{v^{*}}
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{equation}

Where V* and P are bivariately normally distributed (do not assume independence). And

\begin{equation}V=D_{v>a}V^{*}+(1-D_{v>a})a \end{equation}

With D=1 if the condition is met, and 0 otherwise. We can interpret this as: whenever v is lower than a, it becomes a instead. This is a **censored**, not truncated, process.

My attempt at finding a solution is as follows, start with the general formula for the bivariate unconditional expectation for the latent variable:

\begin{equation}
E[V^{*}P]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V^{*}P \phi{(v^{*},p)} dp  dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

Introduce substitution, with the indicator dummy.

\begin{equation}
E[VP]=E[(D_{v>a}V^{*}+(1-D_{v>a})a)P]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (D_{v>a}V^{*}+(1-D_{v>a})a)P \phi{(v^{*},p)} dp dv^{*}  
\end{equation}

Since (thx Daniel)!:

\begin{equation}E[VP \mid V^{\ast} < a] = \frac{E[VP \cdot\mathbb{1}_{V^{\ast} < a}]}{P[V^{\ast} < a]}
\end{equation}

If we condition, we can rewrite as:

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{1}{P[V^{\ast} < a]} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (D_{v^{*}>a}V^{*}+(1-D_{v^{*}>a})a)P \phi{(v^{*},p)}   dp  dv^{*}
\end{equation}

Since under the integration bounds, v* is always smaller than a, we can simplify:

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{1}{P[V^{\ast} < a]}\int_{-\infty}^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} aP \phi{(v^{*},p)} dp  dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

Using, the fact that a is a constant, and the fact that the joint is the product of marginal and the univariate.

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{a}{P[V^{\ast} < a]} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*}) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P  \phi{(p|v^{*})} dp dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

Here the right term is the expectation of the marginal, which we can substitute.

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{a}{P[V^{\ast} < a]} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*}) [\mu_{p} + \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}*(v^{*} -\mu_{v^{*}})] dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

Re-arranging, using linearity of integrals:

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{a}{P[V^{\ast} < a]} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*})(\mu_{p} -\mu_{v^{*}} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}) dv^{*} + \frac{a}{P[V^{\ast} < a]} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*}) v^{*} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2} dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

Next, we introduce: \begin{equation}\alpha= (a-\mu_{v^{*}})/\sigma_{v}\end{equation}. We know that the integral of a pdf is its cdf, so:

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=\frac{a}{\Phi(\alpha)}(\mu_{p} -\mu_{v^{*}} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}) \Phi(\alpha)  + \frac{a}{\Phi(\alpha)} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*}) v^{*} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2} dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E[VP|v^{*}<a]=a(\mu_{p} -\mu_{v^{*}} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2})   + \frac{a}{\Phi(\alpha)}  \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2} \int_{-\infty}^{a} \phi(v^{*}) v^{*}  dv^{*} 
\end{equation}

The right integral is nothing but the univariate conditional truncated expectation.

\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=a(\mu_{p} -\mu_{v^{*}} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2})  + \frac{a}{\Phi(\alpha)} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}  \Phi(\alpha)[\mu_{v^{*}}-\sigma_{v^{*}}\Phi(\alpha) \frac{\phi(\alpha)}{\Phi(\alpha)}] 
\end{equation}

Expanded:
\begin{equation}
E[VP|V^{*}<a]=a [\mu_{p} -\mu_{v^{*}} \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}   +  \frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}}{\sigma_{v^{*}}^2}\mu_{v^{*}}  -\frac{\sigma_{v^{*},p}\phi(\alpha)}{\Phi(\alpha)\sigma^2}]
\end{equation}

This looks like an elegant solution (middle terms cancel out), however when simulating **I get different outcomes numerically when mean and variance of v* are not 0 and 1 respectively.** Meaning I still have made an error somewhere along the way. Please note that the variance of P apparently doesn't matter (it appears not to matter when I simulate,), which seems counterintuititive but ok.

[thx Daniel for pointing out an earlier error, which I made twice in my derivation].

See code for a quick comparison:

```
#simulate bivariate normal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm

nsim=500000

m1=1
m2=0 #this is censored
s1= 1   
s2=1
s12=0.5
a=-.3

mu=[m1, m2]
sigma=[[s1, s12],[s12, s2]]

simulation = pd.DataFrame(np.random.multivariate_normal(mu,sigma,nsim))
simulation.columns=['X','V*']



alpha= (a-m2)/s2

simulation['V']=simulation['V*']
simulation['censor']=simulation['V*']<a
simulation.loc[simulation['censor'] , 'V'] = a
#plt.scatter(simulatie['X'], simulatie['V'])

PhiA=norm.cdf(alpha, loc=m2, scale=s2)
phiA=norm.pdf(alpha, loc=m2, scale=s2)

simulation['VX']=simulation['V'].multiply(simulation['X'])

analytic_expectation=a* (m1- (s12*phiA)/(PhiA*s2*s2))
numerical_average=(simulation['VX'].multiply(simulation['censor'])).mean() *(nsim/simulation['censor'].sum())
print("numerical_average:    ", numerical_average )
print("analytic_expectation:    ", analytic_expectation )
```

Comment: Did not check all your computations, but I am suspicious that your mistake is you are confusing $E[VP \mid V^{\ast} < a]$ with $E[VP \cdot \mathbb{1}_{V^{\ast} < a}]$. Notice that $$E[VP \mid V^{\ast} < a] = \frac{E[VP \cdot\mathbb{1}_{V^{\ast} < a}]}{P[V^{\ast} < a]}$$

Comment: Thx, will ammend derivation.

Comment: Did a rewrite based on your correct suggestion..Answer is still incorrect but I feel like we're getting closer